# Collapse Character Vector to Long Format in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to convert my dataframe from wide to long but based on the character vector in one column (based on residents number from the following dput.)

From the following dput, the outcome should have a total of three rows showing all the 3 residents. Is there a way to do it? I tried using seperate rows but the output is not what I desire.

Tried using

```
Building_Details_Trial_50 %>% tidyr::separate_rows(residents)
```

dput

```
structure(list(time = "Mar 22", buildingId = "50", region = "Central", 
    geometry = structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(-447.361154068258, 
    -447.557850744738, -533.811390293442, -536.961556093902, 
    -443.736917153567, -447.361154068258, 5919.51770006977, 5906.87385860642, 
    5908.2156806004, 5958.8966109417, 5959.54382538916, 5919.51770006977
    ), dim = c(6L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
    "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -536.961556093902, 
    ymin = 5906.87385860642, xmax = -443.736917153567, ymax = 5959.54382538916
    ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = NA_character_, 
        wkt = NA_character_), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L), 
    count = 3L, geom_points = structure(list(structure(c(-490.403818453599, 
    5933.7360887923), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
    "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -490.403818453599, 
    ymin = 5933.7360887923, xmax = -490.403818453599, ymax = 5933.7360887923
    ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = NA_character_, 
        wkt = NA_character_), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L), 
    long = -490.403818453599, lat = 5933.7360887923, residents = list(
        c("556", "155", "143"))), row.names = 1L, sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(time = NA_integer_, 
buildingId = NA_integer_, region = NA_integer_, count = NA_integer_, 
long = NA_integer_, lat = NA_integer_, residents = NA_integer_
), levels = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), class = c("sf", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Ideal output

| Residents | buildingId | Region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 556 | 50 | Central |
| 155 | 50 | Central |
| 143 | 50 | Central |

Comment: try `unnest_longer`: `Building_Details_Trial_50 %>% unnest_longer(residents)`